# Typescript Inheritance, how to define a data member used in parent but defined in subclasses

Tags: typescript

```
class Parent {
   foo: number;
   protected value: number;
   constructor(foo) { this.foo = foo }
   some_function() { return this.foo + this.val }
}

class childClass extends Parent {
   constructor(foo) { super(foo); this.value = 10;
}
```

The problem with the above code is that value is only defined in the subclass and not the Parent. That would make the Parent incomplete.
How do I define or set value considering its definition will only be defined in the child class

Comment: I think you need to abstract class maybe.

Comment: Do you intend to allow `Parent` to be instantiated directly? I.e. `const foo = new Parent(0)`

Comment: @ConnorLow I think so, I can probably just do what JSmart532 suggested ( add value in the constructor of the parent)

Answer (score 1):

Make it a parameter of the parent's constructor and pass it in that way. Maybe this?

```
class Parent {
   constructor(
     public foo: number,
     protected value: number
   ) {}
   some_function() { return this.foo + this.val }
}
```